# How to switch to the Desktop of Windows Service

Tags: c#, windows, windows-services, desktop

I created a windows service and marked the CheckBox "Allow service to interact with desktop" in "Log On" tab of service properties. The service opens a windows application (.exe) but I don't know that what is the progress of the opened .exe. Is there a way that I could switched to the desktop of the service?

The service "logged on as" is "Local System"

(I am sure that the .exe is opened by the service because when I try to modify/move/delete, the message is returned that it is being used by another process)

Comment: No: From Windows Vista onwards a service may not interact with a users desktop.  If you have to do this you would make the service monitor the exe in some way itself and use a form of IPC with another bit of software running on a users desktop to communicate progress reports.

Comment: @AlexK., I am suing Windows 7 Professional and couples of days earlier when I stated the service, a popup appeared on my desktop telling me that a message sent by application, and on clicking the button on popup, it showed me a new desktop that was containing the application opened.

Comment: Yep, that's "interactive services detection", designed to provide minimal functionality for legacy services.  It kicks in if a legacy service appears to be asking for the user's input.  There's no way AFAIK to trigger it manually.  It might be possible for your service to take a screenshot or something, I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

Services do not have a desktop, so you can't switch to it. They *might* have very limited Windows-version-dependent access to a *user's* desktop, but you can't count on it and shouldn't use it.

Also, if you're running terminal services in a version of Windows that can do desktop I/O and the service is configured for it, the I/O goes to the first desktop. If that's not you, you won't see it.

> I am sure that the .exe is opened by the service because when I try to modify/move/delete, the message is returned that it is being used by another process

You would need to stop the service before you can move/delete/replace the exe.